# jQuery window.matchMedia conflicting functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Struggling to understand how this actually works. The code works as intended, but for some reason when the window is resized, and the new functions fired, the old ones are still firing, too, so it's a mess. :-/

I'm sure there is a better way to write this. I only want "isMobile" to run when max-width: 1024 and "isNotMobile" when max-width is greater than 1024, but only one running, not both simultaneously. Is there a better way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {

        var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 1024px)");
        var isNotMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1024px)");

        if (isMobile.matches) {
            $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass("active");
            $('#wpi-page-left').addClass("not-active");

            $( '#wpi-page-center' ).click(function(e) {
                var $this = $('#wpi-page-left');
                if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
                    $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass('active');
                    $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
                    $('#wpi-page-left').addClass('not-active');
                }
            });
            $( '#mobile-toggle-btn' ).click(function(e){
                var $this = $('#wpi-page-left');
                if ($this.hasClass('not-active')) {
                    $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass('not-active');
                    $('#wpi-page-left').addClass('active');
                    $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
                } else if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
                    $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass('active');
                    $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
                    $('#wpi-page-left').addClass('not-active');
                }
            });
        } else if (isNotMobile.matches) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $( '#wpi-page-left' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            }, 1000);

            var timer;
            var delay = 350;

            $('#wpi-page-left').hover(function() {
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#wpi-page-left').addClass( 'active' );
                    $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass( 'not-active' );
                }, delay);
            }, function() {
                $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass( 'active' );
                $('#wpi-page-left').addClass( 'not-active' );
                clearTimeout(timer);
            });
       }
      $("#dimensions").html($(window).width());
}).resize();
```

});

**UPDATE:**

Here's a FIDDLE showing the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/hwqegaza/9/

I added instructions in my fiddle, but basically load the page, and hover over the bar or click the mobile version (depending on width that page is loaded), now resize page and try to use different versions of the menu. You'll see both versions are running. :-/

Comment: `else` is your friend.

Comment: I tried else if, but still same result. It's like I have to refresh the page either below or above 1024 to get it to work properly. Whenever I try to resize, the classes go crazy in Dev Tools console... It's like they're trying to do both :(

Comment: These two queries should not overlap, and you are calling this function only in the $.ready handler. So I am not sure I really get what you are talking about. Can you provide an [MCVE]?

Comment: @kaiido yes, check my fiddle for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are adding `$.hover` event handlers many, many times, without ever removing them, so even though you attached them for the desktop view, they are still active in the mobile view.

---

But let's do a bit more cleaning in all this code, at the risk of becoming a bit verbose:

First, avoid as much as possible to hook on the `resize` event, or only to perform minimal tasks. This event may fire at a great rate (can be >100th of times per second), and manipulating the DOM at such a frequency can cause bottlenecks, let alone adding new event handlers...

Instead, since you are already using the [MediaQuery API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList), use it plenty and hook your function in its [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange) handler.
Also, given your queries, a single one is needed. Either it matches one, either it matches the other one <sub>(if you really need to check for '*(only screen)*', I would advice making an other query just for that, but there is little chance it does change during the document's lifespan in a meaningful way).</sub>

---

Now that we do handle the MediaQuery change properly, it's time to change the `$.hover` and `$.click` handlers:
You could remove it every time you get back to the mobile view, and add it again when going to desktop view, but a cleaner way IMO is to attach these events only once, and simply handle both cases in the handler functions themselves, and exit prematurely when in the wrong view.

It may give us something like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // a single MediaQuery
  var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 800px)");
  // toggle the classes when our MediaQuery will change
  isMobile.onchange = toggleMobile;
  toggleMobile(); // do the initial one

  function toggleMobile() {
    if (isMobile.matches) {
      $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass("active");
      $('#wpi-page-left').addClass("not-active");

      $('#wpi-page-center').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $('#wpi-page-left');
        if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
          $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass('active');
          $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
          $('#wpi-page-left').addClass('not-active');
        }
      });
    } else { // if we're not in mobile, then we are in desktop
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass('active');
      }, 1000);
    }
    $("#dimensions").html(isMobile.matches ? 'Mobile' : 'Desktop');
  };

  // this needs to be called only once
  (function attachHoverHandlers() {
    var timer;
    var delay = 350;
    // attach the event listeners
    $('#wpi-page-left').hover(onhoverin, onhoverout);

    function onhoverin() {
      if (isMobile.matches) return; // if mobile view, then do nothing

      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#wpi-page-left').addClass('active');
        $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass('not-active');
      }, delay);
    }

    function onhoverout() {
      if (isMobile.matches) return; // if mobile view, then do nothing

      $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass('active');
      $('#wpi-page-left').addClass('not-active');
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  })();

  // So does this
  $('#mobile-toggle-btn').click(handleMobileClick);

  function handleMobileClick(e) {
    if (!isMobile.matches) return;

    var $this = $('#wpi-page-left');
    if ($this.hasClass('not-active')) {
      $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass('not-active');
      $('#wpi-page-left').addClass('active');
      $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
    } else if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
      $('#wpi-page-left').removeClass('active');
      $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
      $('#wpi-page-left').addClass('not-active');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

.label {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#wpi-page-left {
  flex: 0 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #2E323C;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease;
  -ie-transition: all 0.15s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}

#wpi-page-left .fa,
#wpi-page-left .label {
  color: #FFF;
}

#wpi-page-left ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wpi-page-left ul>li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#wpi-page-left ul>li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #181a1f;
}

#wpi-page-left #wrap-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #logo {
  flex: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #logo-inactive {
  flex: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 auto;
}

#wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#sidebar {
  flex: 1 250px;
}

#wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#sidebar>li a {
  padding: 8px;
}

#wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#sidebar #mobile-logo-ext {
  display: none;
}

#wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#mobile-bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 0 60px 0;
  display: none;
  width: 60px;
}

#wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#mobile-bar>li {
  width: 100%;
}

#wpi-page-left ul#sidebar {
  display: none;
}

#wpi-page-left ul#sidebar-inactive {
  display: block;
}

#wpi-page-left ul#sidebar-inactive>li {
  text-align: center;
}

#wpi-page-left.active {
  flex: 0 210px;
  width: 210px;
}

#wpi-page-left.active #wrap-menu #logo {
  display: block;
}

#wpi-page-left.active #wrap-menu #logo-inactive {
  display: none;
}

#wpi-page-left.active #wrap-menu ul#sidebar {
  display: block;
}

#wpi-page-left.active #wrap-menu ul#sidebar-inactive {
  display: none;
}

#wpi-page-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  background: #F1F5FA;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

#wpi-page-center .panel {
  flex: 1 auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #cbdaed;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #wpi-page-left {
    flex: 0 80px;
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #logo {
    display: none;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #logo-inactive {
    display: none;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 80px;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #logo {
    flex: 0 auto;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #logo-inactive {
    flex: 0 auto;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 auto;
    min-width: 80px;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#mobile-bar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 120;
    background: #2E323C;
    flex: 1 80px;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #181a1f;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#mobile-bar li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#mobile-bar li:first-child {
    text-align: center;
    height: 61px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #181a1f;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#mobile-bar li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#mobile-bar li a {
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    color: whitesmoke;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#mobile-bar li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    background: #2E323C;
    left: -330px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
    flex: 1 250px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease;
    -ie-transition: all 0.15s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s ease;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#sidebar.active {
    left: 80px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#sidebar li#mobile-logo-ext {
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu ul#sidebar-inactive {
    display: none;
  }
  #wpi-page-left #wrap-menu #menu.active ul#sidebar {
    left: 50px;
    order: 2;
  }
  #wpi-page-left.active {
    flex: 0 80px;
    width: 80px;
  }
  #wpi-page-left.active #wrap-menu #logo {
    display: none;
    flex: 0 auto;
  }
  #wpi-page-left.active #wrap-menu #logo-inactive {
    display: none;
    flex: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wpi-page-left">
  <div id="wrap-menu">
    <div id="logo">
      <span class="fa fa-css3 fa-2x"></span><span class="label">COMPANY NAME</span>
    </div>
    <div id="logo-inactive">
      <span class="fa fa-css3 fa-2x"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul id="mobile-bar">
        <li>
          <span class="fa fa-css3 fa-2x"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a id="mobile-toggle-btn" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="sidebar">
        <li id="mobile-logo-ext">
          <span class="label">COMPANY</span>
        </li>
        <li id="item1">
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="fa fa-file-word-o fa-fw"></span><span class="label">Menu Item 1</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="item2">
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="fa fa-file-archive-o fa-fw"></span><span class="label">Menu Item 2</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="item3">
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-fw"></span><span class="label">Menu Item 3</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="item4">
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="fa fa-file-code-o fa-fw"></span><span class="label">Menu Item 4</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="sidebar-inactive">
        <li id="item1">
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="fa fa-file-word-o fa-fw"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="item2">
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="fa fa-file-archive-o fa-fw"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="item3">
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-fw"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="item4">
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="fa fa-file-code-o fa-fw"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wpi-page-center">
  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Page mode: <span id="dimensions"></span></h2>
    <p>
      Resize from above 800px to below 800px, or vice versa. You'll see that both are running. The hover stuff shouldn't be active when below 800px, but it is... :(
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for all of that @kaiido, really appreciate the explanations, too. I obviously need to do some more reading and keep practicing. This was helpful, and solved the problem. Marking as answer and voting up! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an event listener to the `resize` event of your current window to make it work.
Your code as is implies that only when the DOM is ready you perform the check, that's why you need to reload each time your viewport width changes.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // your code
  // e.g check the width: console.log($(this).innerWidth());
});
// OR
$(window).resize(() => console.log($(this).innerWidth()))
```

[jQuery docs on resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

[MDN window.innerWidth docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)

Comment: Also OP is complaining that his code gets called too many times.

Comment: @t3__rry see my fiddle above for more details

Comment: Actually, adding "$(window).resize(function() {" partially works, but the other functions are still running, so you have two sets conflicting. How do you cancel/terminate one once the page is resized to the appropriate value?